# Left factoring grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, formal-languages

I am trying to build a recursive decent parser with backtracking. Here is my grammar:

```
Re -> Sq | Sq + Re
Sq -> Ba | Ba Sq
Ba -> El | Ba*
El -> lower-or-digit | (Re)
```

After trying a lot of things i am having problems with the production     **Sq−>Ba|BaSq** And i end up with infinite recursion here. So a possible solution i found for this is left factoring the grammar.

My problem is that the production i wanna left factor does not seem to match any of the examples i found. How can i left factor the grammar? Or is there another teqnique that i can use?

Comment: `Ba | Ba Sq` should not cause infinite recursion. It simply requires infinite lookahead or backtracking. You can fix that by left-factoring, but if you're okay with backtracking anyway, you don't actually need to do that. What's likely causing your infinite recursion is that your `Ba` rule is left-recursive.

Comment: For the record, left-factoring is generally trivial. For example, transform `Sq->Ba|Ba Sq` into `Sq->Ba Sq'; Sq'->ε | Ba Sq'`. Indeed, a very similar transform can be used to remove the left-recursion in `Ba->El|Ba*`; `Ba->El Ba'; Ba'->ε | * Ba'`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<Sq>` is a non-terminal (or the grammar won't be CFG) and `<Ba>` also is a non terminal :

```
Sq -> Ba Z

Z -> epsilon | Sq
```

Comment: Note that, while this does correctly left-factor `Sq`, it does not help with the infinite recursion that OP is running into.